# How to perform DCD in C using __asm?

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m, armcc

I am trying to do the ASM instruction `DCD 0xf7f0a000` in ARM C code.

The below methods I tried and errors I got:

```
__asm("DCD 0xf7f0a000");
```

> Error : #3061: unrecognized instruction opcode

```
__asm
{
MOV r0,=0xf7f0a000
MOV r1,{r0}
}
```

> Error: Implicit physical register R0 should be defined as a variable.
>
> Error: Implicit physical register R1 should be defined as a variable.

**Update:**

ARM Compiler Version: `ARM Compiler 5.06 update 6`

PS: I am trying to generate an exception by doing undefined operation.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  GNU C (gcc/clang) uses GAS directives like `.long 0xf7f0a000` or `.int` to emit literal data inside an `asm("");` statement.  And to generate an exception, you can use `__builtin_trap()`.  [How do I set a software breakpoint on an ARM processor?](//stackoverflow.com/q/11345371)

Comment: I am using ARMGCC compiler. I tried `DCD 0xf7f0a000` in assembly file which works. But I need the same to work C also.

Comment: I tried using `__builtin_trap()`. It says  `L6218E: Undefined symbol __builtin_trap`

Comment: Are you sure you're using ARM *GCC*?  I think ARMCC is a totally different compiler, not supporting GNU extensions like `__builtin_trap()`.

Comment: Sorry. Its ARM compiler, i.e, ARMCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARMCC has very good quality documentation available from the vendor.

You did not specify the version of your ARMCC, apparently things have changed since I used it (~15 years ago).

You need to study this if you want to use inline assembly (again - if this fits your compiler version):
https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/software-development-tools/legacy-tools/ds-5-development-studio/resources/tutorials/using-inline-assembly-to-improve-code-efficiency

> Note: Register names in inline assembly code are treated as C or C++ variables. They do not necessarily relate to the physical register of the same name. In our C code, we use the variable names r5 and r6 for our operands, but the actual registers used are r1 and r2.

Inline __asm can be very cumbersome to use unless you perfectly understand what you're doing. It is usually much easier to place your assembly code into a separate file. (Used to have .asm extension back then, not sure about now).

> PS: I am trying to generate an exception by doing undefined operation.

As far as I can see, you are trying to write into invalid address, this is not the same as 'undefined operation' and you can do this from C using an invalid pointer, no need for asm at all:

```
int *a;
a = 0xf7f0a000;
*a = 2019;
```

Another edit: And finally answering the actual question in the title :) I don't think you can. DCD is not an opcode, it is an assembler directive, it can't be used within __asm block (inline assembly), it can only be used in the 'real' assembly language code.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use the asm rules provided in the links in your answer and successfully compile. But the output is not what I expected. I guess I will go with C approach.

Comment: For C, we can go with  *((volatile unsigned int *)(0xf7f0a000)). Gives no errors.